# Inverted tags order in CKEditor using "extractContents"

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I created a custom plugin for CKEditor 4.

I need to retrieve all tags in a selection and wrap them in a parent tag. It works fine when there is only one tag level. If I select parent and nested tags and I exctract them with `extractContents` method; second level tags are inverted.

For example I have the following markup:

```
<p>test string1</p>
<p>test string2</p>
<blockquote>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>6</p>
</blockquote>
```

Calling `extractContents` on selection:

```
 var containers = [];
 var fragment = editor.getSelection().getRanges()[0].extractContents();
 var mySectionElement = new CKEDITOR.dom.element('my-section', editor.document);
 fragment.appendTo(mySectionElement);
 editor.insertElement(mySectionElement);
 containers.push(mySectionElement);
```

I recieve `fragment` variable with childNodes:

```
<p>test string1</p>
<p>test string2</p>
<blockquote>
    <p>6</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>1</p>
</blockquote>
```

Have you ever notice something like this? How can I prevent it?